# More areas in contourf using logscale

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to get an impression of continuous change in my contour plot. I have to use a logscale for the values, because some of them are some orders of magnitude bigger than the others.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

K = np.linspace(-0.99, 5, 100)
x = np.linspace(1, 5, 100)
K, x = np.meshgrid(K, x)
static_diff = 1 / (1 + K)
fig = plt.figure()
plot = plt.contourf(K, x, static_diff, locator=ticker.LogLocator(numticks=300))
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('K')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.xlim([-0.99, 5])
plt.ylim([1, 5])
fig.colorbar(plot)
plt.show()
```

Despite the number of ticks given to be 300 it returns a plot like:[image]

Is there a way to get more of these lines? I also tried adding the number of parameters as the fourth parameter of the `plt.contourf` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the levels of a contourf plot you may

- use the `levels` argument and supply a list of values for the levels. E.g for 20 levels,

  ```
  plot = plt.contourf(K, x, static_diff, levels=np.logspace(-2, 3, 20))
  ```
- use the `locator` argument to which you would supply a matplotlib ticker

  ```
  plt.contourf(K, x, static_diff, locator=ticker.LogLocator(subs=range(1,10)))
  ```

  Note however that the `LogLocator` does not use a numticks argument but instead a `base` and a `subs` argument to determine the locations of the ticks. [See documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator).

Complete example for the latter case, which also uses a `LogNorm`to distribute the colors better in logspace:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import matplotlib.colors

K = np.linspace(-0.99, 5, 100)
x = np.linspace(1, 5, 100)
K, x = np.meshgrid(K, x)
static_diff = 1 / (1 + K)
fig = plt.figure()
norm= matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=static_diff.min(), vmax=static_diff.max())
plot = plt.contourf(K, x, static_diff, locator=ticker.LogLocator(subs=range(1,10)), norm=norm)
#plot = plt.contourf(K, x, static_diff, levels=np.logspace(-2, 3, 20), norm=norm)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('K')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.xlim([-0.99, 5])
plt.ylim([1, 5])
fig.colorbar(plot)
plt.show()
```

[image]